# Django - Static Images are not rendering from JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-views, django-staticfiles

On my Django project, I keep receiving a not found error for a few images. When running the project without Django (using live server), everything works fine.

I have loaded static at the beginning of the html document and added all of the correct static tags. I believe it has something to do with my JavaScript File (where the image is used).

For Example the html code where it pulls the JavaScript file

```
<script src="{% static '/js/project.js'%}"></script>
```

And the JavaScript File (project.js)

```
const projects = [
  {
    title: "Discord App",
    cardImage: "/images/project-page/download.png",
    description: "A Discord app.",
    tagimg: "https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-512/react-1-282599.png",
    Previewlink: "",
  },
];
```

I have a few images that are not on the JS file (only html) that work fine. Was wondering if anyone ran into the same problem and could help me out. Let me know if you need more information.

**Static_Url Setting**

```
STATIC_URL = '/staticfiles/'
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

STATICFILES_DIRS =[ 
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
]
```

Comment: What's your STATIC_URL setting? I think your issue is you have the incorrect path for your image, it should probably begin with something like "/static/"

Comment: @Iain Shelvington  I edited the Static_url setting above.

Comment: Which is the image that is not loading? Is it "cardImage" and is it a static or media file?

Comment: Yes the "cardimage" is not loading. And it is a staticfile.

Comment: Something like "/staticfiles/project-page/download.png" or "/staticfiles/images/project-page/download.png" might work? Either way if it's a static file it should begin with "/staticfiles/"

Comment: I tried using staticfiles/images/project-page/download.png but it did not work.